# Does the Nest API provide humidity information?

Tags: nest-api

In looking over the [Thermostat Guide](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/thermostat-guide) I don't see any mention of humidity readings. Is this data available through the API? Will it be in a later release?

Comment: It's probably worth putting your method of using the unofficial API to get the humidity readings as an answer.  You'll probably get buckets and buckets of rep that way.

Comment: Well that's hard to turn down. I'll polish the pieces up a bit and get them online.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an API/Tools/Software Library and not about the actual code itself.

Comment: The Nest API documentation directs developers to this tag for "More questions about using the API? Check Stack Overflow". For example, see the bottom of: developer.nest.com/documentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of NestAPI v1.1 it appears that humidity data is available as a read only field.

More information can be found in the v1.1. [release notes](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/release-notes?utm_campaign=tahoe_1dot1_announcement&utm_source=registriaemail&utm_medium=email&utm_content=learn-more]).

Comment: Any idea why it's rounded to nearest 5%? The device gives you a more precise reading.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately that is correct, humidity is not available in the current version of the API.

Nest has not shared a roadmap for the API either, so availability in a future version is unknown at this time.

---

Updating with [nate-f comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26890523/262133) from below:

> As of NestAPI v1.1 it appears that humidity data is available as a
>   read only field.
>
> More information can be found in the v1.1. [release notes](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/release-notes).

Comment: I guess I'm sticking with the unofficial APIs for the moment then. At least to get that data. Thanks.

Comment: @fracai - Unofficial APIs? Can you tell me more?

Comment: @RichardEverett I'm using [this](https://www.npmjs.org/package/unofficial-nest-api), but there are others. Also, I'm not sure how much is exposed nicely, I'm basically subscribing to all available data and then parsing out temperature and humidity from the JSON that comes back. I was hoping the official API would be more complete, but it's missing info like humidity that would be rather useful. Hope this helps.